# MySQL Master/Slave Master/Master setup?

Tags: mysql, replication

I currently have 1 mysql server running and want to install 2 seperate mysql VPS'es. Maybe one master for inserts/updates and one slave for selects. What is the best setup for this if I have the following requirements:

- Run backups on machine
- When my mysql backups run on the slave machine it generates a high load. Can the master decide to take over some selects to reduce the loads?

Is there a way that the master decides where to execute the query (load balancing)? Is it possible to send all queries to one master and the master decides if he sends it to the slave, so I don't have to make 2 connections in my php code (1 for select, 1 for updates)?

Thanks,
Ward

Answer (score 4):

You might look into [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy). Features include:

- load balancing
- failover
- query analysis
- query filtering and modification

I haven't run it myself, but it seems to cover what you want.

**UPDATE**

Apparently the [Read/Write splitting](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy_RW_Splitting) is a proof of concept and not for production use